Junit test on eclipse for a Maven, error comes "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors"
I have a created a simple Maven project and running a test runner class using Junit and I see error as below
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.getTestClassNames(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:50)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:39)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.java:46)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.reportEngineFailure(OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:203)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:94)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Well most of the solutions on stack flow are related to Spring Boot project, but mine is simple maven project so i could not try any one of solution so far.

This is most likely a version mismatch problem. Please post your pom.xml.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
